# do az login from python script and capture device code

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cli

from a python program i want to run **`az login --use-device-code`** and capture the code and display it to user along with the URL.
We will have a frontend for user to login
If this runs via subprocess or azure.cli.core should be fine.

Comment: Why not use MSAL? There is a sample of using the library with device code flow: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow/blob/master/device_flow_sample.py

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @juunas that you can alternatively use `msal` and you will get device code for that too and I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results :

```
import msal

c = "3a4d9391"
a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f9db47"
appli = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id=c, authority=a)
s = ["https://storage.azure.com/.default"]
output= appli.initiate_device_flow(scopes=s)
print(output["message"])
```

Here **c** is your client id
**a** is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid`
and **s** is the scope you want to give to the user.

[image]

Here you got **URL** and **CODE** .